# Remote state taxes

Tags: united-states, income-tax, state-income-tax, new-york, florida

I live in Florida and I work remotely to a New York office and I am being paid thru their payroll not 1099.  The employer has been deducting NY state tax and I know Florida does not have state tax.

I live and work here at Florida.  How do I get a refund of all the NY state taxes that the employer have deducted from my payroll?  What forms do I need to fill out in order to get a refund?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that you'll have to file a non-residential tax return in NY. I'm not sure what that would mean in terms of tax liability but according to [this article](https://money.cnn.com/2018/05/30/pf/taxes/work-from-home-tax-increase/index.html) you might end up paying more taxes than if you had the same job in Florida.

I recommend talking to a tax professional to see what rules apply in your specific case.

Comment: That article seems to be about people who tele-commute and work in the office, not people who exclusively tele-commute.